# Обратимое XOR шифрование текста со случайной гаммой

Tags: шифрование

Привет.
Наткнулся на [статью](http://denik.od.ua/xor_text_encoding/), где приведен пример работы XOR, но не понятен приведенный им пример:

> Допустим, у нас есть открытый текст -
> "**denik.od**" Придумаем для него гамму:
> "**12345678**" (гамма должна быть равной
> длине текста, т.к. мы весь текст хотим
> зашифровать). Конкретный пример рассмотрим на первых 2-х байтах "**de**" (представим их в двоичной системе):
>
> Имеем **d 1 e 2** Это же, только в двоичной системе **1100100 0110001 1100101 0110010**

Каким образом у автора, d в двоичной системе 1100100, а цифра 1 в двоичной 0110001 ? Объясните, пожалуйста, если не сложно, может я что-то не правильно понимаю.

Comment: Честно говоря, меня "статья" ужаснула, а вот Шнайер наверное с инфарктом в больницу слег :-/ Купите в букинистическом Жельникова хотя бы...

Comment: Вообще -- метод довольно прост. Я чисто мельком услышал про него и решил подумать. сел, умножил символ на символ(и обратно), смастерил первый набросок. в итоге у меня довольно быстрая шифрующая программа. но в общей сложности я писал ее около полугода -- от метода тыка, до полной отладки.  
и кстати гамма не обязана быть той же длины -- просто пройдите ее покругу несколько раз

Comment: @Илья Михневич, гамма должна быть *длииииинной* и **случайной**. Тогда расшифровать (говорят) трудно (очень). 

Если же ее использовать *по кругу* (в простейшем случае так можно использовать сам пароль), то расшифровать (длинный текст) значительно проще.

Comment: [Шифр Вернама](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: Спасибо всем за комментарии, но я не использую этот метод я в целях самообучения, чтоб знать. К чему столько минусов, не я статью писал, мне просто инфа нужна была, за которую Вам всем спасибо. За Вермана отдельное спасбо, буду знать.

Comment: @avp спасибо

Comment: @karmadro4,
честно говоря, не понял почему Вас так испугала моя статья :) Вы бы хоть как-то аргументировали свое недовольство.

**К автору:** почему не откомментировали на источнике? Любопытно просто...

*PS: надо будет наверно действительно дописать, что ASCII используется.*

Comment: Не знаю как его,

> пожалуй самым надежным [...] методом шифрования будет XOR-метод

А меня вот тут покоробило. Если длина сообщения будет намного больше 20 байт, разумеется.

Comment: Что же вы читаете отдельные фразы... Прочитайте абзац выше, слова после "пожалуй самым надежным" - да, именно те что в "[...]". Речь шла о совокупности, тут еще бралась во внимание простота реализации. КОНЕЧНО, есть куда более надежные методы. Но если вы ограничены средствами и временем - то этот самый подходящий.

Comment: Я в «[...]» просто для цитирования сократил.

Суть в том, что надежно оно, разве что, по сравнению с простой перестановкой (зато перестановка значительно проще: `return str_rot13($str)`). Реализация, скажем, RC4 [почти так же проста](http://ideone.com/Yhp6i), хотя RC4 тоже ерунда. Но последний хоть школьник с блокнотом, карандашом и свободной минуткой не сломает.

А вообще, если кто-то хочет шифрования и ограничен временем и отсутствием mcrypt — ему надо просто [найти](https://www.google.com/search?q=pure+php+aes) и скачать уже написанную и проверенную реализацию AES, да и дело с концом.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за статью, просто в 90% случаев никто не отвечает на комментарии :)(это моя личная статистика, ничего личнего).

Comment: @drdaemon, зря Вы про XOR так пишите. Все ведь дело в длине и случайности гаммы, которой шифруется текст, а не методом смешивания ее с текстом. 

Вот об этом в своих комментариях Вы не говорите. Похоже прицепились к шифрованию текста наложением циклически повторяющегося пароля.

Попробуйте на досуге ломануть text XOR циклический md5(pass). Я намеренно (провакационно) говорю об md5, поскольку все считают эту функцию "легко ломаемой". Попробуйте.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На самом деле тут все просто. Здесь берутся символы по таблице символов `ASCII`. И число, представленное в двоичном виде, есть ничто иное, как номер(код) символа в таблице ASCII.
Так, символ **"d"** имеет порядковый номер в таблице 100( 1100100 в двоичной ), соответсвенно, символ **"e"**( КЭП: идет после буквы "d" в английском алфавите ) имеет порядковый номер 101(1100101 в двоичной). Точно так же обстоит дело и с цифрами:

```
1 - 49 - 110001
2 - 50 - 110010
```

Comment: О, спасибо большое, совсем вылетил из головы ASCII. Благодарю Вас.